# Was the negative zone gate at 42 breached?

Tags: marvel, comics, guardians-of-the-galaxy

In Guardians of the Galaxy, we see the prisoners of 42 and Blastaar's forces take over the Negative Zone side of the portal leading to Earth. Then we see the Guardians warn Reed Richards to keep the gate closed whatever it takes. What happens then? Was the gate ever breached?

Answer (score 1):

No. In Avengers: The Initiative the prison is retaken by the Shadow Initiative and is back under earth control.

Comment: You should add evidence to support your answer.

Comment: Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers:_The_Initiative#Dark_Reign_2) has an overview of when the Shadow Initiative helped to re-take 42 in the Negative Zone.